# optimize nested for loops dataframes python by spliting the data

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to iterate through two data frames (df1,df2 )in a certain columns(index, F_Date ), I used

```
for i in df2.index:                 
               
    for j in df1.F_Date:

        A0=df2['X'][i]
        A1=df2['Y'][i]
        A1=df2['Z'][i]
        df1.loc[(df1['ID'] == A0) & 
       (df1['F_Date'] ==j ), 'Rule'] = 'A0 Occuar'
       df1.loc[(df1['ID'] == A1) & 
       (df1['F_Date'] ==j ), 'Rule'] = 'A1 Occuar'
       df1.loc[(df1['ID'] == A2) & 
       (df1['F_Date'] ==j ), 'Rule'] = 'A2 Occuar'
```

But it enter infinity loop, how can I optimize or split data to patches as when I tried to split data

```
split_df = np.array_split(df1, 20) 
for j in split_df.F_Date:
```

I Got the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'F_Date'

Example df1

| ID | F_Date | Clear_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 |
| CD | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-03 |
| EF | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-04 |

df2

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | CD | EF |

I want to iterate through on every day on df1 and each row in df2 and check if X, Y, Z happened on this date or not then if happen make some calculation on this times and the output will be the time difference between the max value of X, Y and the time of Z.

Expected output

| X | Y | Z | Time_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | CD | EF | 25:00 |
| CD | AB | EF | 28:00 |
| EF | AB | CD | 02:30 |

Comment: Pls post sample of data and expected output. I am sure this can be done without loops

Comment: And explain the expected logic in detail

Comment: @asmaamahmoud for clarity, please provide the matching expected output

Comment: Also your example in unclear, you have `df2.F_Date` in your code but `df1` has this column.

Comment: Please show the expected output. It is still missing.

Comment: My main problem is to optimize the nested for loop, I need optimized nested iterator

Comment: @asmaa sorry but your question is missing important details. For instance, how is the Time Difference computed? Why is `Y` receiving CD/AB/AB? and Z EF/EF/CD? If we can't understand the logic and "compute" it with a pen and paper then your question is not clear enough. Please provide specific details.

Comment: CD , AB, and EF are just examples. I want to Known when they occur on df1 and get the date of X and Y  and choose the maximum of them, then get time difference between this max and the time of Z

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you might want to have something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AB','CD', 'EF'], 
                    'F_Date': ['2023-10-01', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-02'],
                    'Clear_Date': ['2023-10-02', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-04']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['AB'], 
                    'Y': ['CD'],
                    'Z': ['EF']})

df2 = df2.reset_index(names='rowid').melt(id_vars = 'rowid', value_vars = ['X','Y', 'Z'],var_name='Event', value_name='ID')


result = df1.merge(df2)

result.loc[result['Event'] == 'X', 'Event'] = 'A0 Occuar'
result.loc[result['Event'] == 'Y', 'Event'] = 'A1 Occuar'
result.loc[result['Event'] == 'Z', 'Event'] = 'A2 Occuar'

print(result)
```

This yields:

```
   ID      F_Date  Clear_Date  rowid      Event
0  AB  2023-10-01  2023-10-02      0  A0 Occuar
1  CD  2023-10-02  2023-10-03      0  A1 Occuar
2  EF  2023-10-02  2023-10-04      0  A2 Occuar
```

I use `pd.melt` to unpivot the second df and then you only require `pd.merge` on the ID and have your answer.

Comment: I got TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Comment: which pandas version are you using?